# jupyter lab is launching old version

Tags: jupyter, version, upgrade, jupyter-lab, launch

After upgrading to jupyterlab 4, jupyter is still launching the old version, version 3.

I'm using the same command as always: `jupyter lab`

Indeed, the [jupyterlab 4 documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/starting.html) says that's the command you must use to launch it:

> Start JupyterLab using:
>
> jupyter lab

But it launches jupyterlab 3 instead.

It might be wise to simply uninstall jupyterlab 3. But it is said there can be problems with backwards compatibility. So I want to keep it to hand for a while, in case I find I need it for an old notebook.

In either case, I want to be able to control which version I open.

Comment: You need to install the two versions in separate virtual environments and then start them up from respective environment.

Comment: Well, you are right, of course. That will avoid the problem happening. It is the wisest way to approach lib management. But still, sometimes you just don't. Like sometimes you eat cake and cola. And sometimes you don't exercise and just flop in front of the TV with your belly hanging out after eating a huge, greasy takeout.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if I launch with the command `jupyter lab`, it launches version 3, and if I launch with `jupyter-lab`, it launches version 4. Go figure.